# Winsorize a matrix

Tags: dataframe

I want to winsorize a matrix with 6 columns and non NA and no infinite values.

I use the `robustHD` package and the code

```
winsorize(df)
```

but I get the following error message:

> Error in eigen(R, symmetric = TRUE) : infinite or missing values in 'x'

Does anyone know whats the problem or is there another way of doing this with another package I could try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Winsorizing is very simple, and very flexible. It's easy to create a function of your own design. The difficult part is deciding on what design is the most suitable.

One example

```
set.seed(1)

mat <- matrix(sample(-99:99, 30), 6)

ran <- quantile(mat, c(0.20, 0.80))

mat.w <- mat
mat.w[mat < ran[1]] <- ran[1]
mat.w[mat > ran[2]] <- ran[2]

mat.w - mat

#       [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4] [,5]
# [1,]   0.0 -38.8   0.0   0.0  0.0
# [2,]   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0  0.0
# [3,]   0.0   0.0   0.0 -23.8 36.8
# [4,] -34.8  27.8   0.0   1.8  0.0
# [5,]   0.0   0.8   0.0   0.0 -4.8
# [6,] -30.8   5.8 -36.8  16.8  0.0
```

Here we've made it so that everything below the twentieth percentile is clamped to that value, and everything above the eightieth percentile is clamped to that value. That makes this version of winsorizing symmetric about the median, and the median won't be changed (unlike with trimming), but the mean will.

```
median(mat.w) - median(mat)
# 0

mean(mat.w) - mean(mat)
# -2.6667
```

---

That way of winsorizing, based on percentiles, is probably the most common approach, but there's no real limit or rules to how it should be done.

For example, we can base it on deviations from the mean.

```
cen <- mean(mat)
range(mat - cen)
# -91.8  88.2
```

We see that the values deviates from the mean at 91.8 below and 88.2 above at the most. Say we want to limit that to 70? Easy.

```
mat.w <- mat
mat.w[mat - cen < -70] <- -70
mat.w[mat - cen >  70] <-  70

mat.w - mat

#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    0  -13    0    0    0
# [2,]    0    0    0    0    0
# [3,]    0    0    0    2   27
# [4,]   -9   18    0    0    0
# [5,]    0    0    0    0    0
# [6,]   -5    0  -11    7    0
```

And so on. Any winsorizing method you'd desire, easy peasy.